# downloading images with progessbar percentage

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Hi in the below downloading images for showing progessbar to 100 but completeld 100% images are not showing still downloading and not showing .i want after 100% i want to move to activity.

But it's taking time to move next activity.

**java**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            final DialogProgressBarRunnable progressDialog =
                    new DialogProgressBarRunnable(getActivity(), false, 2);
            progressDialog.show();
            // the dialog box shouldn't get cancelled when clicking outside it or pressing back button.
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

           // pd.setMessage("Downloading catalogue images.");
           // pd.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... Params) {


            parsingObject = new ParsingForFinalImages(catid, responseJson);
           /* ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity().getBaseContext());
            Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

            if (isInternetPresent==true)
            {

            }
            */

            // put your code here
            // JSON parsing begins here via the parsing class
            // Put this code in async task


            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
           // pd.hide();
          //  pd.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ImageGallery.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
    private class DialogProgressBarRunnable extends ProgressDialog implements
            Runnable {
        private boolean showSecondary;
        private int incrementAfter;

        public DialogProgressBarRunnable(Context context,
                                         boolean showSecondary, int incrementAfter) {
            super(context);
            setCancelable(true);
            setMessage(getString(R.string.download_message));
            setSecondaryProgress(0);
            setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            setMax(100);
            setProgress(0);
            this.showSecondary = showSecondary;
            this.incrementAfter = incrementAfter;
        }

        @Override
        public void show() {
            super.show();
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progress < 100) {
                progress++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // increment the first/second progress bar after every %
                progressBar();
            }
        }

        private void progressBar() {
            if (progress % incrementAfter == 0) {

                progressFirstBar();
            }
            if (showSecondary) {
                progressSecondaryBar();
            }
        }

        private void progressSecondaryBar() {
            while (secondaryProgress < 100) {
                secondaryProgress++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        setSecondaryProgress(secondaryProgress);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        private void progressFirstBar() {
            secondaryProgress = 0;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setProgress(progress);

                    if (progress == 100) {

                        dismiss();

                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask {

```
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Declear Variables

        int count;
        try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conection = url1.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url1.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Report.xls");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                Log.d("Downloding"+data,"Count"+count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }



    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String reString) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        super.onPostExecute(null);;
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
        Log.d("Download","Completed");
        Intent intent1=new Intent(DownloadExcle.this,MainActivity.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
}
```